# How do I change the background color of the placeholder in jquery-ui sortable

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-ui

I'm trying to color the background color of the placeholder in a sortable table red. 
I can't however make it work.
I already tried the commonly used way of styling it with a class in a css file, but without succes.

```
placeholder: 'ui-sortable-placeholder',
```

css

```
.ui-sortable-placeholder{
        background-color: red;
}
```

nor did styling it in javascript directly work.

```
start: function(e, ui) { 
ui.placeholder.css({
  "visibility":"visible",
  "background-color": "red"
});
```

},

The preferred outcome would be a solution directly in javascript

```js
var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
  ui.children().each(function() {
    $(this).width($(this).width());
  });
  return ui;
};

$("table tbody").sortable({
  axis: 'y',
  containment: 'parent',
  revert: true,
  helper: fixHelper,
  start: function(e, ui) { 
    ui.placeholder.css({
      "visibility":"visible",
      "background-color": "red"
    });
  },

}).disableSelection();
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

th {
  background-color: #dce0e3;
}

.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  background-color: #fff;
  outline: 0px dashed black;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus </td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari </td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#placeholder - Can set a class name to be used for the placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
  ui.children().each(function() {
    $(this).width($(this).width());
  });
  return ui;
};

$("table tbody").sortable({
  axis: 'y',
  containment: 'parent',
  revert: true,
  helper: fixHelper,
  placeholder: "my-ui-placeholder"
}).disableSelection();
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

th {
  background-color: #dce0e3;
}

.my-ui-placeholder {
  outline: 0px dashed black;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}

.my-ui-placeholder td {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus </td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari </td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Remember that this is being added to the `tr`, and it will have `td` elements within it. So your CSS has to apply to both.

Comment: This seems quite broken. Try to reorder a couple of times.